# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Не могу разобраться с Retrofit json/Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

С помощью POJO Generator создал такие классы

```
    package com.treamz.evan.myap1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Track implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("artist")
@Expose
private String artist;
@SerializedName("url")
@Expose
private String url;
@SerializedName("streamable")
@Expose
private String streamable;
@SerializedName("listeners")
@Expose
private String listeners;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private List<Image> image = new ArrayList<Image>();
@SerializedName("mbid")
@Expose
private String mbid;
private final static long serialVersionUID = -7725218454254070904L;

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getArtist() {
return artist;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
this.artist = artist;
}

public String getUrl() {
return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
this.url = url;
}

public String getStreamable() {
return streamable;
}

public void setStreamable(String streamable) {
this.streamable = streamable;
}

public String getListeners() {
return listeners;
}

public void setListeners(String listeners) {
this.listeners = listeners;
}

public List<Image> getImage() {
return image;
}

public void setImage(List<Image> image) {
this.image = image;
}

public String getMbid() {
return mbid;
}

public void setMbid(String mbid) {
this.mbid = mbid;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.treamz.evan.myap1.TrackSearch.java-----------------------------------

package com.treamz.evan.myap1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TrackSearch implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("results")
@Expose
private Results results;
private final static long serialVersionUID = 858036293905063495L;

public Results getResults() {
return results;
}

public void setResults(Results results) {
this.results = results;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.treamz.evan.myap1.Trackmatches.java-----------------------------------

package com.treamz.evan.myap1;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Trackmatches implements Serializable
{

@SerializedName("track")
@Expose
private List<Track> track = new ArrayList<Track>();
private final static long serialVersionUID = 2298673177635891516L;

public List<Track> getTrack() {
return track;
}

public void setTrack(List<Track> track) {
this.track = track;
}

}
```

GetTraclSearch.class

```
public interface GetTrackSearch {
@GET("2.0/?method=track.search&format=json&api_key=b70be2524d5997e0c0901d3480965f4e")
Call<List<Results>> getData(@Query("track") String trackName);}
```

App.class

```
public class App extends Application {

private static GetTrackSearch gettracksearch;
private Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com") //Базовая часть адреса
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Конвертер, необходимый для преобразования JSON'а в объекты
            .build();
    gettracksearch = retrofit.create(GetTrackSearch.class); //Создаем объект, при помощи которого будем выполнять запросы
}

public static GetTrackSearch getApi() {
    return gettracksearch;
}
```

}

MainActivitiy

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static GetTrackSearch gettracksearch;
private Retrofit retrofit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    App.getApi().getData("Believe").enqueue(new Callback<List<Results>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Results>> call, Response<List<Results>> response) {
            //Данные успешно пришли, но надо проверить response.body() на null
            Log.d("OK","OK");

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Results>> call, Throwable t) {
            //Произошла ошибка
            Log.d("ERR",t.toString());
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: Скорее всего из `Call<List<Results>>` надо просто убрать `List`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT (Retrofit 2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588251/java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-retr)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб это же классика жанра, надо помечать как дубликат. Таких вопросов примерно 10.000 )))))

Answer (score 1):

Вы смотрели ответ сервера, как выглядит JSON?)
Я полагаю что вам приходит некий объект, а-ля response, в котором уже необходимый вам массив.

```
Call<List<Results>> getData(@Query("track") String trackName);}
```

должен выглядеть примерно как

```
Call<ResultList> getData(@Query("track") String trackName);}
```

где ResultList это

```
class ResultList {
   List<Results> list;
   // геттеры и сеттеры
}
```