# Ошибка "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY"

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

В моем приложении кнопка отправляет из текстового поля запрос на сервер и дальше я пытаюсь посредством API получить ответ от сервера.

Мой запрос получается в формате JSON:

```
{
    "prompt": "Какой-то текст от меня"
}
```

С сервера приходит ответ:

```
{
  results: 
  [
    {
      text: "Какой-то текст от сервера"
    }
  ]
}
```

Мне нужно ответный текст от сервера поместить отобразить в приложении. Разумеется, если я пытаюсь это сделать, то мне выдает ошибку java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_ARRAY... Знаю, ошибка распространенная и в сети много решений, но у меня так и не получилось ни одно из них адаптировать под себя. Заранее большое спасибо за помощь.

Основной код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private EditText textInput;
    private Button postDataBtn;
    private TextView responseView;
    private ProgressBar loadingPB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textInput = findViewById(R.id.idEdtName);
        postDataBtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnPost);
        responseView = findViewById(R.id.idTVResponse);
        loadingPB = findViewById(R.id.idLoadingPB);

        postDataBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (textInput.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter both the values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                postData(textInput.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void postData(String prompt) {


        loadingPB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://адрес-сайта")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = retrofit.create(RetrofitAPI.class);

        DataModal modal = new DataModal(prompt);

        Call<DataModal> call = retrofitAPI.createPost(modal);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<DataModal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DataModal> call, Response<DataModal> results) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data added to API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                textInput.setText("");


                DataModal responseFromAPI = results.body();

                String responseString = responseFromAPI.getResults();

                responseView.setText(responseString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DataModal> call, Throwable t) {

                responseView.setText("Error found is : " + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}

public class DataModal {

    // string variables for our name and job
    private String prompt;

    private String results;
    public DataModal(String prompt) {
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    public String getResults() {
        return results;
    }
}
```

Код API-интерфейса:

```
public interface RetrofitAPI {
    
    @POST("generate")

    Call<DataModal> createPost(@Body DataModal dataModal);
}
```

Comment: У вас в ответе `results` не строка а массив, который содержит объект, а уже тот содержит строку - именно такую иерархию вам и нужно воссоздать в модели.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT (Retrofit 2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588251/java-lang-illegalstateexception-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-retr)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Решил проблему переходом с Retrofit на Volley. Не тратьте время, Retrofit - днище.

Comment: Retrofit это "HTTP client for Android and Java", сам он ничего не парсит (can only deserialize HTTP bodies into OkHttp's ResponseBody type), но позволяет подключать конверторы, которые эту всю работу и делают. Достаточно просто научиться ими пользоваться.